# How do I call a method on an instance object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, view, model, instance

I have `User` profiles and Users have `Records` that `belong_to` Users. In my `users/show/1` path, I want to only display a records section if a User has Records. So, in my User model, I wrote a method: `has_records?`

```
def self.has_records?(usr)
  return true if User.find_by_id(usr.id).records.size > 0 
end
```

To call this method, I need to write `User.has_records?(user)` in the view, which is really repetitive. Could I refactor the code to be able to say `@user.has_records?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will define method inside `user` model

```
def has_records?(usr)
  self.find_by_id(usr.id).records.size > 0 
end
```

it will work if you want to send other user in `has_records?` method. if you want to check same user then

```
def has_records?
  self.records.size > 0 
end
```

it should work

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @MaximP if it is working could you please accept this answer as a solution , that will be good thanks

Comment: @Arv We generally use implicit return in Ruby. I updated your reply.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti my my apologies i concentrate on the question thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure first you need to change the type of the method from `class method` to `instance method`

so your method inside the `user model` would be like

```
def has_records?
  true if self.records.size > 0
end
```